# Notice: Undefined index: index.php

Tags: php

I' am getting `

> Notice: Undefined index: index.php in
>   xxxxx/index.php on line 26

When I remove the $submenu variable array from menu.php. Everything works fine but when I add $submenu array variable I get error message.
`
What I' am trying to do here is get the top level first and then search if theirs any child submneu

On index.php file I have this code

```
    foreach($menu as $menu){
            $title = $menu[0];
            $privllages = $menu[1];
            $template = $menu[2];
            $class = $menu[3];
            $id = $menu[4];
            $icon = $menu[5];

            if(!$title){$title = 'No Title';}
            if($class){$class = 'class="'.$class.'"';} else {$class = '';}
            if($id){$id = 'id="'.$id.'"';} else {$id = '';}
            if(!$icon){$icon = "menu-default.png";}

            echo '<a href="'.$template.'" '.$class.' '.$id.'>' . $title . '</a>' . "<br/>";

/* LINE 26 Starts here */ 
                if($submenu[$template]){
                    foreach($submenu[$template] as $submenu){
                        echo '<a href="#">' . $submenu[0] . '</a>' . "<br/>";
                    }
                }
        }
```

On menu.php file

```
$menu[1] = array('Dashboard', '0', 'index.php', 'sidebar-menu','','menu-dashboard');
$menu[2] = array('Pages', '0', 'pages.php', 'sidebar-menu','','menu-dashboard');
$menu[3] = array('Media', '0', 'media.php', 'sidebar-menu','','menu-dashboard');
$menu[4] = array('Tools', '0', 'tools.php', 'sidebar-menu','','menu-dashboard');
$menu[5] = array('Users', '0', 'users.php', 'sidebar-menu','','menu-dashboard');
$menu[6] = array('Settings', '0', 'settings.php', 'sidebar-menu','','menu-dashboard');

$submenu['pages.php'][1] = array( 'All Links 1', 'admin-menu', 'manage_links', 'link-manager.php' );
$submenu['pages.php'][2] = array( 'All Links 2', 'admin-menu', 'manage_links', 'link-manager.php' );
$submenu['pages.php'][3] = array( 'All Links 3', 'admin-menu', 'manage_links', 'link-manager.php' );
$submenu['pages.php'][4] = array( 'All Links 4', 'admin-menu', 'manage_links', 'link-manager.php' );
```

Comment: Which line in your example is 26?

Comment: hi I have edited the question with comment of /* LINE 26 Starts here */

Comment: Instead of `if($submenu[$template]){` try `if(array_key_exists($template,$submenu)){`

Comment: @user3140617 have you check my answer

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Instead of

```
if($submenu[$template]){
```

use

```
if(!empty($submenu[$template])){
```

This will then only trigger if $submenu[$template] exists and is not empty

Answer (score 1):

try with this modified code. errors are mentioned in the code

```
<?php
$menu[1] = array('Dashboard', '0', 'index.php', 'sidebar-menu','','menu-dashboard');
$menu[2] = array('Pages', '0', 'pages.php', 'sidebar-menu','','menu-dashboard');
$menu[3] = array('Media', '0', 'media.php', 'sidebar-menu','','menu-dashboard');
$menu[4] = array('Tools', '0', 'tools.php', 'sidebar-menu','','menu-dashboard');
$menu[5] = array('Users', '0', 'users.php', 'sidebar-menu','','menu-dashboard');
$menu[6] = array('Settings', '0', 'settings.php', 'sidebar-menu','','menu-dashboard');

$submenu['pages.php'][1] = array( 'All Links 1', 'admin-menu', 'manage_links', 'link-manager.php' );
$submenu['pages.php'][2] = array( 'All Links 2', 'admin-menu', 'manage_links', 'link-manager.php' );
$submenu['pages.php'][3] = array( 'All Links 3', 'admin-menu', 'manage_links', 'link-manager.php' );
$submenu['pages.php'][4] = array( 'All Links 4', 'admin-menu', 'manage_links', 'link-manager.php' );

foreach($menu as $arr_menu){ // problem-1 was  here foreach($menu as $menu)
        $title = $arr_menu[0];
        $privllages = $arr_menu[1];
        $template = $arr_menu[2];
        $class = $arr_menu[3];
        $id = $arr_menu[4];
        $icon = $arr_menu[5];

        if(!$title){$title = 'No Title';}
        if($class){$class = 'class="'.$class.'"';} else {$class = '';}
        if($id){$id = 'id="'.$id.'"';} else {$id = '';}
        if(!$icon){$icon = "menu-default.png";}

        echo '<a href="'.$template.'" '.$class.' '.$id.'>' . $title . '</a>' . "<br/>";
            if(isset($submenu[$template])){  // problem-2 was  here not checking isset
                foreach($submenu[$template] as $arr_submenu){ // problem-3 was  here foreach($submenu as $submenu)
                    echo '<a href="#">' . $arr_submenu[0] . '</a>' . "<br/>";
                }
            }
    }
?>
```

Answer (score 1):

Change

```
if($submenu[$template])
```

to

```
if(!empty($submenu[$template]))
```

Also the following line is ambiguous

```
foreach($menu as $menu)
```

change it to something like

```
foreach($menu as $my_menu)
```